# How to convert Table base design to Table less design page

Tags: html

In my website there is table base design, and I want to convert it into tableless (Div, span, etc). Is there any Tool which will convert this automatically.

Answer (score 1):

No, there won't be any tool. Its up to you to decide how you can implement with divs and spans.

Here is a nice article that you can refer

[Tableless Layouts Using CSS Positioning to Layout Web Pages](http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/a/aa102102a.htm)

Answer (score 1):

There's no tool that I know of. Floating DIVs will be a good starting point from a coding perspective. The trouble with automatic conversion is knowing which tables are layout. Tables do have a purpose, i.e. displaying data in a tabular format. You would never want to 'DIV' these.

I might be worth reading through some fo the web accessiblity guidelines, as there may be suggestions there. Converting from layout tables falls in line with some of these requriements.

Answer (score 0):

I agree there won't be any tool for this.

It's not easy without an automatic method, but I found the best incentive to move away from tables is to look at websites such as [CSS Zen Garden](http://www.csszengarden.com/).

It impressed me how much the appearance and layout of a website can change *just with changes to the CSS*. I realised that using tables for layout is just wrong.